# How to match the onther collection data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My name is Brighton and I'm an Android Developer. Lately, I have been studying the MongoDB database which has been very difficult for me and need your help.

**FirstCollection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5628c5b27ad4a27341f7be6d"),
    "name" : "Ace",
    "address" : "Seuol",
    "reservations" : [ 
        {
            "token" : "f59c6e0a99dabbe2b954bf9fd31bc23e1c07b6079345aa84255ad5e6d457fd523e1387048dd9a31392bfd25dbe6c093386dff31904d20064d7981ef2da4ab11d",
            "productnumber" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**SecondCollection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561710b47ad4a27341f7be18"),
    "productnumber" : 2,
    "productprice" : "47",
    "category" : "Fix",
    "name" : "Oil"
}
```

I want to get a result which replaces the value of `productnumber` in `FirstCollection` with the actual document in `SecondCollection` using only a find query. This is the expected result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5628c5b27ad4a27341f7be6d"),
    "name" : "Ace",
    "address" : "Seuol",
    "reservations" : [
        {
            "token" : "f59c6e0a99dabbe2b954bf9fd31bc23e1c07b6079345aa84255ad5e6d457fd523e1387048dd9a31392bfd25dbe6c093386dff31904d20064d7981ef2da4ab11d",
            "productnumber" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("561710b47ad4a27341f7be18"),
                "productnumber" : 2,
                "productprice" : "47",
                "category" : "Fix",
                "name" : "Oil"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I input the query? I can't find any solution. When I input the data, do I have to input all of those data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the tags in your question, you would need asynchronous calls to both collections since you want the result using Mongoose. To understand the concept, consider the operation in mongo shell.

With the solution in mongo Shell, iterate the cursor from the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method to access the documents in the  `FirstCollection` and manipulate the `reservations` array using the native JavaScript method **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**, getting the new values using the **[`findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne)** method on the `SecondCollection`. Something like the following code in mongo Shell:

```
var cur = db.reservation.find({"reservations": { "$exists": true, "$type": 4 } });
cur.forEach(function (doc){
    var reservations = doc.reservations.map(function (r){
        var product = db.product.findOne({"productnumber": r.productnumber});
        return { 
            "token": r.token,        
            "productnumber": product
        }
    });
    doc.reservations = reservations;
    printjson(doc);
})
```

For the given sample data, this will print:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5628c5b27ad4a27341f7be6d"),
    "name" : "Ace",
    "address" : "Seuol",
    "reservations" : [
        {
            "token" : "f59c6e0a99dabbe2b954bf9fd31bc23e1c07b6079345aa84255ad5e6d457fd523e1387048dd9a31392bfd25dbe6c093386dff31904d20064d7981ef2da4ab11d",
            "productnumber" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("561710b47ad4a27341f7be18"),
                "productnumber" : 2,
                "productprice" : "47",
                "category" : "Fix",
                "name" : "Oil"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For a solution in Mongoose, you would need call the **[`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)** method before **`exec()`** on the `find()` query since documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects, 
hence you can manipulate the documents by replacing the `productnumber` field value with the document in the `SecondCollection`

From the Mongoose **[documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)**:

```
Model.find().lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
    docs[0] instanceof mongoose.Document // false
});
```

So your code should look like (given that `Reservation` model refers to the `FirstCollection` and Product model to `SecondCollection` ):

```
var Reservation = mongoose.model('reservations');
var Product = mongoose.model('product');

Reservation.find()
    .lean()
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
        if(err) return res.send(err);

        async.forEach(docs, function(doc, done) {
            _.each(doc.reservations, function(resv, i) {
                Product.findOne()
                        .where('productnumber')
                        .equals(resv.productnumber)
                        .lean()
                        .exec(function(err, product) {
                            resv.productnumber = product;
                            done(err);
                        });             
            });         
        }, function(err) {
            // ... you have reservations with products
            console.log(docs[0]);           
            // res.send(docs);      
        });        
    });
```

Comment: Thansks for your teaching, so I did try first example but It's was be occur error
2015-10-25T08:31:48.284+0000 TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined

Comment: I think I know why, some of your documents don't have the `reservations` field hence the `map()` method in the loop throws as error as it tries to map on an existing array field. I edited my answer to correct this. Also, would be helpful to read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

in your schema add ref to anothe collection

```
"reservations" : [{
        "token" : String,
        "productnumber" : {type:Number, ref:'secendCollection'}
    }]
```

and use mongoose populate

```
schema.find({your query}).populate('reservations.productnumber').exec(callback function)
```

[see the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html)